# Multi threaded insert using ORM?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, database-design, jpa

I have one application where `"persisting to database"` is consuming 85% time of the entire application flow.

I was thinking of using multiple threads to do the insert because inserts are mostly independent here. Is there any way to achieve multi threaded insert using any of JPA implementation ? Or is it worth doing the mutli threaded insert, from improving the performance perspective ?

Note: Inserts are in the range of 10K to 100K records in a single run. Also performance is very very critical here.

Thanks.

Comment: could you give some more details? like database being used, the fragment (method) of your code. Seems a bit weird that this could impact that much your application.

Comment: You are going to probably need more than application redesign to gain the efficiency you are seeking. If your underlying db table is not designed in such a way as to support multiple inserts then all the application optimization in the world will not help. Case in point, are you able to avoid index locks on your table during insert?

Comment: @woliveirajr , @Perception  . [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514117/jpa-persistence-using-multiple-threads) is the use case. The database used is Oracle and eclipselink as ORM provider.

Comment: from that use case any multi-threading you introduce will probably make performance even worse with lock contention and IO bandwidth issues the main things that will be negatively impacted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Multi-threading insert statements on database won't really make it perform any faster** because in **most** databases the table requires a lock for an insert.  So your threads will just be waiting for the one before it to finish up and unlock the table before the next can insert - which really doesn't make it any more multi-threaded than with a single thread.  If you where to do it, it would **most likely slow it down**.

If you inserting 10k-100k records you should consider using either **batch insert statements** or **bulk insert commands** that are native to the database your using.  The fastest way would be the native bulk insert commands but it would require you to not use JPA and to work directly with JDBC calls for the inserts you want to use bulk commands on.

If you don't want to play around with native bulk commands I recommend using Spring's [JDBCTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html) which has templated batch insert commands.  It is very fast and I use it to batch insert 10k-20k entities every 30 seconds on a high transaction system and I am very pleased with the performance.

Lastly, make sure your database tables are optimized with the correct indexes, keys and options.  Since your database is the bottleneck this should be one of the first places you look to increase performance.

Comment: Which databases lock the table for an insert?  That's not true for Oracle and I'd guess it's not true for most other databases as well.

Answer (score 4):

> Multi-threading insert statements on database won't really make it perform any faster 
>   because in most databases the table requires a lock for an insert. So your threads will 
>   just be waiting for the one before it to finish up and unlock the table before the next can 
>   insert - which really doesn't make it any more multi-threaded than with a single thread. If 
>   you where to do it, it would most likely slow it down.

Are you saying concurrent inserts from different db connections on the same table require exclusive locks to complete?  I tested this on Oracle, and I didn't find this to be the case.  Do you actually have a test case to back up what you wrote here?

Anyway, bulk insert is of course a lot faster than one insert at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you periodically flushing your session when doing this?  if not, you can hit nasty slowdowns that have nothing to do with the database.  generally, you want to "batch" the inserts by periodically calling `flush()` then `clear()` on your session (assuming you are using some variant of JPA).

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html) has many tips to improve batch writing performance with JPA. I'll quote the two that should give you the best result for fast reference.

> Optimization #6 - Sequence
> Pre-allocation
>
> We have optimized the
> first part of the application, reading
> from the MySQL database. The second
> part is to optimize the writing to
> Oracle.
>
> The biggest issue with the writing
> process is that the Id generation is
> using an allocation size of 1. This
> means that for every insert there will
> be an update and a select for the next
> sequence number. This is a major
> issue, as it is effectively doubling
> the amount of database access. By
> default JPA uses a pre-allocation size
> of 50 for TABLE and SEQUENCE Id
> generation, and 1 for IDENTITY Id
> generation (a very good reason to
> never use IDENTITY Id generation). But
> frequently applications are
> unnecessarily paranoid of holes in
> their Id values and set the
> pre-allocaiton value to 1. By changing
> the pre-allocation size from 1 to 500,
> we reduce about 1000 database accesses
> per page.
>
> Optimization #8 - Batch Writing
>
> Many
> databases provide an optimization that
> allows a batch of write operations to
> be performed as a single database
> access. There is both parametrized and
> dynamic batch writing. For
> parametrized batch writing a single
> parametrized SQL statement can be
> executed with a batch of parameter
> vales instead of a single set of
> parameter values. This is very optimal
> as the SQL only needs to be executed
> once, and all of the data can be
> passed optimally to the database.
>
> Dynamic batch writing requires dynamic
> (non-parametrized) SQL that is batched
> into a single big statement and sent
> to the database all at once. The
> database then needs to process this
> huge string and execute each
> statement. This requires the database
> do a lot of work parsing the
> statement, so is no always optimal. It
> does reduce the database access, so if
> the database is remote or poorly
> connected with the application, this
> can result in an improvement.
>
> In general parametrized batch writing
> is much more optimal, and on Oracle it
> provides a huge benefit, where as
> dynamic does not. JDBC defines the API
> for batch writing, but not all JDBC
> drivers support it, some support the
> API but then execute the statements
> one by one, so it is important to test
> that your database supports the
> optimization before using it. In
> EclipseLink batch writing is enabled
> using the persistence unit property
> "eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing"="JDBC".
>
> Another important aspect of using
> batch writing is that you must have
> the same SQL (DML actually) statement
> being executed in a grouped fashion in
> a single transaction. Some JPA
> providers do not order their DML, so
> you can end up ping-ponging between
> two statements such as the order
> insert and the order-line insert,
> making batch writing in-effective.
> Fortunately EclipseLink orders and
> groups its DML, so usage of batch
> writing reduces the database access
> from 500 order inserts and 5000
> order-line inserts to 55 (default
> batch size is 100). We could increase
> the batch size using
> "eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size",
> so increasing the batch size to 1000
> reduces the database accesses to 6 per
> page.