# Achieving multi tasking

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can I achieve multi tasking in Spring/JPA.

Having a service which perform two tasks

1. update a record
2. search a record.

These two are independent task. Since there is no need for one to wait for other task to finish.

During some research I found there is `@Scheduled` which can be used to schedule tasks.
But here the scenario is different, solution for parallel processing of 2 independent tasks.

Which JPA API can be used here to achieve multi taking?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA persistence using multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514117/jpa-persistence-using-multiple-threads)

Comment: You can use Spring , ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Answer (score 1):

I think that rather than relying on JPA APIs , use thread pools to carry out these tasks.
Thread1 from pool executing search while record updation on Thread2.
This way it will be lot simpler Even if you prefer to use other ORM frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Async` annotation for this purpose. To enable asynchronous execution support in Spring boot, you will need annotate you main class with `@EnableAsync`.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class MyApplication{

}
```

And then add `@Async` to your query.

**Example:**

```
@Async
Future<User> findByFirstname(String firstname);               

@Async
CompletableFuture<User> findByFirstname(String firstname); 

@Async
ListenableFuture<User> findByLastname(String lastname);
```